# Scala boilerplate: lack of common superclass of Iterable and ParIterable

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, iterable, boilerplate

Why is Scala designed with the following irritating form of boilerplate?

It would be convenient to write

```
def doStuffWithInts(ints: BaseIterable[Int]): Unit = ints foreach doStuffWithInt
```

for a common superclass BaseIterable of Iterable and ParIterable so that we can write both

```
val sequentialInts: Vector[Int] = getSomeHugeVector()
doStuffWithInts(sequentialInts)
```

and

```
val parInts: ParVector[Int] = getSomeHugeParVector()
doStuffWithInts(parInts)
```

Yet Scala forces us to copy and paste our doStuff method, once for Iterable and once for ParIterable. Why does Scala thrust such boilerplate on us by failing to have a common superclass BaseIterator of both Iterator and ParIterator?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `IterableOnce` but that would force you to get an `Iterator` which is always sequential.

This is a conscious decision from the maintainers, you can read all the related discussions by starting here: https://github.com/scala/scala-parallel-collections/issues/101
The TL;DR; is that the maintainers agree that it is a bad idea to provide an abstraction between two; mainly because parallel collections should not be used as general collections but rather as localized optimizations. Also, the point out how easy it would be to introduce errors if you could abstract over the two *(as was the case in `2.12`)*.

Now, if you insist you want to abstract over the two, you may create your own **typeclass**.

---

Finally, I may suggest looking at using `Future.traverse` instead of parallel collections.

Comment: Thanks Luis. Unfortunately that page you linked to only shows opinions on either side of the issue, rather than a definitive answer. The issue with introducing errors only occurs with IterableOnce because it silently transforms a parallel collection into a sequential one. Following the philosophy of "it should just work", surely there's no reason why my code above "shouldn't just work", right?

Comment: @PerfectTiling well, it depends on what you mean with _"definitive answer"_. All I can say is that the answer is _"not, is no possible"_ and then adding why, which is that the maintainers agree that in the general case is a bad idea. In your example if `doStuffWithInt` has a side-effect that is affected by order of execution then that is a problem; you may say no that is not my case, which is great but is not the common rule _(or, at least, that is what maintainers think)_. - Another answer is that if you are so sure you want this, then you can create your own **Typeclass** to abstract them.