# Scala: ParVector does not conform to upper bound [_] =>> Seq[?]

Tags: scala, generics, collections, parallel-processing, scala-3

I am using Scala 3.1.3 with the parallel collections module, version 1.0.4 ([Github](https://github.com/scala/scala-parallel-collections)).
I have the following type definition defining a generic version of a matrix:

```
type Matrix[T, C[_] <: Seq[_]] = C[C[T]]
```

As expected, initializing such a matrix works when using Vector as the collection type:

```
val vecMatrix: Matrix[Double, Vector] = 
  Vector(Vector(0.5, 0.6), Vector(0.6, 0.8))
```

However, using ParVector instead yields a compiler error:

```
val parvecMatrix: Matrix[Double, ParVector] =
  ParVector(ParVector(0.5, 0.6), ParVector(0.6, 0.8))
```

> Type argument collection.parallel.immutable.ParVector does not conform to upper bound [_] =>> Seq[?]

I read this as meaning ParVector is not a subtype of Seq. However, the documentation of scala.collection.parallel.ParSeqLike, a linear supertrait of ParVector, explicitly states:

> Parallel sequences inherit the `Seq` trait.

Is the documentation wrong? Or is there an issue with my code that prevents the upper bound from working?

Comment: It inherits a different `Seq` trait. Abstracting over sequential and parallel collections was forbidden by design.

Comment: okay thanks. that makes sense at least as far as the reason for the error goes. Do you happen to know why they decided to forbid it?

Comment: Check this and the linked github discussions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70818870/scala-boilerplate-lack-of-common-superclass-of-iterable-and-pariterable/70819003#70819003